# Add category in post type dynamically

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

i have the code that can add a post in a custom post type but adding the category is not working.

```
$args = array(
    'post_title' => $title ,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'mypost' 
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

$category_ids = array(38,39);
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $category_ids, 'category');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the custom post type with support for the `category` taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_register_post_type');
function cyb_register_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        // All the other args
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'my_post_type', $args );
}
```

Then you can set relationships between the custom post type and the `categoy` taxonomy as you was doing, but you have to correct the code.

From this:

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $category_ids, 'category');
```

To this (previous categories are deleted and replaced by the new categories):

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $category_ids );
// The above line is equivalent to
// wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $category_ids, false );
// or
// wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $category_ids, 'category', false );
```

Or to (previous categories are not deleted, new categories are appended):

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $category_ids, true );
```

You can also register a custom taxonomy and use it for your custom post type:

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_register_post_type_and_taxonomy');
function cyb_register_post_type_and_taxonomy() {

    $post_type_args = array(
        // All the other args
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'my_custom_taxonomy' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'my_post_type', $post_type_args );

    $taxonomy_args = array(
          // Arguments for the custom taxonomy
          // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'my_custom_taxonomy', 'my_post_type', $args );

}
```

And then use `wp_set_post_terms()`, not `wp_set_post_categories()`:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $category_ids, 'my_custom_taxonomy');
```

Comment: i already registered the post type and taxonomy, the problem is that the post that i created dynamically can't set category

Comment: Please, [edit the question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/293491/edit) and provide that part of the code where you register the post type and the taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this for the custom post type, you need to use taxonomy. I will suggest you `<?php wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ) ?>` to use.
please refer [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) for the detailed use of the function.